# Server Sent Events with PHP not displaying data properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, server-sent-events

I am trying to create the most simplest chat app using ajax posting and trying to push the data with SSE. I just came across SSE and tried my hands on it. Now the problem is

1. How can I control when the Server will push data since it is pushing the data every 3 seconds.
2. Why when I select the the whole MySQL row only showing the last row in my browser but pushing everything (checked in the network tab)

Here's my code :

index.html

```
<script>

var source = new EventSource("server.php");

source.addEventListener("message", function(event){

$("#box").html(event.data);

});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
function chat_pressed(){

    var chat = $('#chat_text').val();

    var data = {action : "send_chat", chat : chat};

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "chat.php",
        data : data,
        success : function(r){
            $('#chat_text').val("");
        }

    })


}

</script>

<input type="text" id="chat_text" />
<input type="button" onClick="chat_pressed();"  value="POST"/>
<br /><hr />
<div id="box"></div>
```

server.php

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

include("connect.php");


$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM chat");
$sql->execute();

while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $chat = $row['chat'];
echo "data: $chat \n\n";
}

ob_flush();
flush();

//sleep(2);
```

1. On `index.html` when I change `$("#box").html(event.data);` to `$("#box").append(event.data);` then it's displaying all the rows same thing over and over again. Basically appending.

What happening here is it's displaying only the last row when I keep `$("#box").html(event.data);`

2. When on `server.php` I write `echo "data:".$chat."<br />"` , then it is not pushing anything.

   What I want is to get control over the server pushing thing and to append only the last row of data to the current data when the table gets updated. And I want to know a proper way of `echoing` data since when there are complicating things like `divs` and all it will get difficult, as I have understood. Any help here would be appreciated..

Comment: is event.data even text, or just an object. `html` requires a string, while `append` can handle a lot more types.

Answer (score 1):

Your server.php process ends after sending one bit of data. This means the socket closes. The browser sees the socket has died and re-connects after 3 seconds. That is why it looks like it is pushing data every 3 seconds. Instead, you need to change your server.php to have an infinite loop, that has a sleep in it, and polls mysql:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

include("connect.php");

$previousID = 0;

while(true){
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id > ?");
    $sql->execute( array($previousId) );
    while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $chat = $row['chat'];
        echo "data: $chat \n\n";
        //TODO: update $previousID here
    }

    ob_flush();
    flush();

    sleep(10);  //Poll every 10 seconds
}
```

This (untested) code also shows how to only send the new data each time. You need to make it a bit more robust - if 0 rows are received you might want to send a heartbeat to tell the client the last poll time, for instance.

For your second question, your message handler is called for each piece of data you sent, and then you do:

```
$("#box").html(event.data);
```

That means each new piece of data overwrites the previous one; as all the rows of data arrive at effectively the same time, all you were seeing on-screen was the data row that arrived last.

Consider using `<li>` tags, and jQuery's `append()`, if you want all rows to be on-screen. In my book (PLUG: Data Push Apps with HTML5 SSE - O'Reilly) I often append to a `<pre>` tag, as a quick-and-dirty way to see all the data that is arriving.